# Where should I save an xml file so it can be written to by a service when Windows is logged off?

Tags: .net, windows, xml, windows-7

Where should I save an xml file so it can be written to by a service (written in C#) when Windows is logged off?

Thanks
Steven

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good place to store data files on Win7 that can be accessed and manipulated by multiple user accounts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492070/what-is-a-good-place-to-store-data-files-on-win7-that-can-be-accessed-and-manipul)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can a user write to that can be accessed by a service when a user is logged off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494786/where-can-a-user-write-to-that-can-be-accessed-by-a-service-when-a-user-is-logged)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.IO.ISOLATEDSTORAGE.ISOLATEDSTORAGE);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true), but the most reasonable is `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` since it saves it on the machine in the user profile for whatever account the service is run from.

Comment: Did you check where LocalApplicationData points to for a Service?

Comment: Ahh, Local System has no user profile and then most of the special folders goes bananas :-(
Then this only works if you start your service from an account with a user profile.