# Where can a user write to that can be accessed by a service when a user is logged off?

Tags: windows-7

Where can a user write to that can be accessed by a service when a user is logged off? When a user runs the program they will be applying settings that a service needs to read, typically a user would need to be an administrator to be able to write to 'Program Files' or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE so is there a correct way to prompt for admin elevation at that point rather than running the program as administrator?

Many thanks
Steven

Comment: Are you doing this from code?

Comment: If the user is logged off, who is going to be around to agree to the admin elevation?

Comment: The elevation would be done when the user is running the program and writing the settings, the service wouldn't need any elevation. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good place to store data files on Win7 that can be accessed and manipulated by multiple user accounts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492070/what-is-a-good-place-to-store-data-files-on-win7-that-can-be-accessed-and-manipul)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should I save an xml file so it can be written to by a service when Windows is logged off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494478/where-should-i-save-an-xml-file-so-it-can-be-written-to-by-a-service-when-windows)